# how to send data to mobile number from browser

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-8

i m working on a phonegap with windows 8.i m unable to select contacts from people app.so i am thniking to send some data to a specific number  by just entering his or her number in a textbox.so pls tell me some way that i can proceed my application..it would be great if that coding is possible through javascript..as i m working on phonegap.i tried by using windows phone 8,but i am unable to do that.with people app i tried that also but i dont know how to pick that contacts and implement to our app.so pls help me..

Answer (score 0):

Sending texts in not a JavaScript feature but you could use JavaScript to contact a webservice that would send the text for you.

An example would be a service like [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/sms).